# How to stub a database query in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, integration-testing, nestjs, cypress

I am trying to write an end-to-end integration test using Cypress. The flow involves querying a database. We want to stub the database call and return a static JSON object that will test every scenario. Is there a way for me to do that with Cypress?

The database query method:

```
export class myClass {
  constructor(private readonly connector: MssqlConnector) {
    super();
  }

  async myQuery() {
    const pool = await this.connector.getConnectionPool();
    const response = await pool.query(q));

    return response.recordset;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're asking, "can I stub an HTTP response?", then the answer is yes. See the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Stubbing) on stubbing in Cypress. If you're asking how to stub a database query, then that's outside of the scope of Cypress, as Cypress is a UI testing framework. That's not to say that it can't be done with the tools provided by the framework, as @Rahul L pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using cy.task

[Example : cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Allows-a-single-argument-only)

```
// in test
const dbName = 'stagingA'
const query = 'SELECT * FROM users'

cy.task('queryDatabase', { dbName, query })



// in plugins/index.js
const mysql = require('mysql')
// the connection strings for different databases could
// come from a config file, or from environment variables
const connections = {
  stagingA: {
    host: 'staging.my.co',
    user: 'test',
    password: '***',
    database: 'users'
  },
  stagingB: {
    host: 'staging-b.my.co',
    user: 'test',
    password: '***',
    database: 'users'
  }
}

// querying the database from Node
function queryDB (connectionInfo, query) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionInfo)

  connection.connect()

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
      }

      connection.end()

      return resolve(results)
    })
  })
}
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    // destructure the argument into the individual fields
    queryDatabase ({ dbName, query }) {
      const connectionInfo = connections[dbName]

      if (!connectionInfo) {
        throw new Error(`Do not have DB connection under name ${dbName}`)
      }

      return queryDB(connectionInfo, query)
    }
  })
}
```